# Typescript: Why is there a difference between passing an object and a variable assigned to that object as an argument?

Tags: typescript, typechecking, object-literal

Why is there a difference between passing a variable assigned to an object literal as an argument(`let x = {color: 'red', width: 200}`), and passing an object literal as an argument (`{color: 'red', width: 200}`)?

**In other words, the value of the argument is the same (`{color: 'red', width: 200}`).

So why does the compiler do excess checking when the object is passed, and "regular shape" checking when variable assigned to that object is passed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the function type signature:

```
type SOME_OBJECT = {
  propA: TYPE_A,
  propB: TYPE_B
}

function foo(obj: SOME_OBJECT) {
  // WILL DO SOMETHING WITH obj
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHkCyBRA+ugIQClsBhAFWQG8BYAKGUeQQHsAbFqALmQGcwooAOYAaek2QB3YABMwACx4gArgFsARtHoBfevTYQwyFuoBWubAA0AghWQBeauKasO3ZACIoEGR5HJnRmk5RWQAJgAGCLE6bQBuPToDIxNzTABJVFR0gDkAcQcnBhd2Th4vHw8dROTjMwtLUmwswtpixlcyz29fGIlghR5I6MDkCAAPATgeAWUIarp9QzrzKyas3GscgBFcDKzcgsc2iU73Ct7RiamZqDmY3UW6GGUQBDBgFhBkGBYWAApUjwMDh8MQyOQAJRFU5fXjsCAAOg4QkBZkhCViiVYIH4yG8vAAjIVfgDUg1bFDMTi8QSwiS-mi0plsvkMfQaUYCQBmBlk+prZqodl0Tn4iC8AAsfKZDXWqE2Oz2LMOIuxcK5EoArDKqGdyj0-FJZINwlFtNCJFaJAB6G3IKyUjka8W8ABsuv13UqFutfv9VrtyH2rLyztxmt4AHZPaVzob-ANQsN-NcoNNkLMIL6g4KsuHaRKAByxtwGyqpybp25zX0Bpi5xpCxW7EOHRL0UCQWCIFAgvCEEgUXAAdXS5AAEvgAArkdLoHLWAAyMJKZb4AmEfSYSaUak0UG3jFUcAAnpoAPw8dR-AxwEALAtGcaE4FYAfg4djyczucL5etKMXoXH4oy7maIztMgJ6nhA6g1iggb2gAPAAtOhDpNi004AEroNO2A4eQACayCkBOZAANKHMgmTIDh2DLkupHpJg07oERWzkI+oouuM9LHEBcblpcUHgSmowwXBCE8S8bwfF8Px-AAamETJvqCg4QqO45Tvhf6Lku0InCUuIIsiLCoqkIqPE+roAJx8qp-wviKYoEoSEROWp-FqnQQA)

In the example above, function `foo` is expecting an object `obj` that has a `propA` of type `TYPE_A` and a `propB` of type `TYPE_B`. As long as something meets those requirements, function `foo` will be able to do its thing. Or at least, that is what its contract is implying. So what should it excess property check the `obj` parameter?

Now let's assign an object literal. Let's say you have a type that has an **optional parameter** `maybe`.

```
interface SOME_OBJECT_WITH_OPTIONAL {
    color: string,
    width: number,
    maybe?: boolean
}

const x1: SOME_OBJECT_WITH_OPTIONAL = {
    color: "red",
    width: 200,
    mayeb: true      // <--- TS ERROR HERE - EXCESS PROPERTY CHECKING IS REALLY IMPORTANT
}
```

See that you've misspelled that `maybe` property as `mayeb`. Thanks to the excess property checking, Typescript warns you that you've made that mistake. Can you imagine the pain if this was not handled like it is? In our example, no property would be missing, since `maybe` is optional, so it's allowed to be missing. You would get no errors or warnings whatsoever.

[image]

A function that expects an `obj` of type `SOME_OBJECT_WITH_OBJECT` still won't mind. Because all the required properties `color` and `width` are present.

[image]

You can read more about this subject here:

[Typescrip Docs - Excess Property Checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks)

[Medium - Introduction to TypeScript Interfaces — Object Literals and Function Types](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-typescript-interfaces-object-literals-and-function-types-3eafa3709336)